# Send login data to the server using AngularJS/Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to send the existing user data on the server with the `$http`-service of angularjs. The user data, so (`loginData`), are created and existing on the backend server. With the information of the user I would like to log in on my mobil phone. How can I compare local entered data with the existing data on the server? My code doesn't work yet.

**the loginService:**

```
myApp.factory('loginService', function($http){
  var endPoint = "https://www.****.***/****/****";
  var loginData =
  {
    "username": "user",
    "password": "pass"
  };

  return{
    login: function(username, password){
      return $http.post(endPoint, loginData);
    }
  }
});
```

**the loginController:**

```
myApp.controller('LoginCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $window, loginService) {

  $scope.logIn = function logIn(username, password) {
    if (username !== undefined && password !== undefined) {

      loginService.login(username, password).success(function(data) {
        $window.sessionStorage.token = data.token;
        $window.location.href = '/index.html';
      }).error(function(status, data) {
        console.log(status);
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-content style="text-align: left" ng-controller="LoginCtrl">
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Name:</span>
      <input name="name" autofocus="true" required="true" type="text"
             ng-model="username"/>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password:</span>
      <input name="password" required="true" type="password"
             ng-model="password"/>
    </label>
    <button id="button-1" class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="logIn(username, password)">
      Login
    </button>
</ion-content>
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: POST https://www.****.***/****/****
No more request expected
    at $httpBackend (angular-mocks.js:1244)
    at n (ionic.bundle.min.js:119)
    at f (ionic.bundle.min.js:117)
    at ionic.bundle.min.js:151
    at n.$eval (ionic.bundle.min.js:165)
    at n.$digest (ionic.bundle.min.js:163)
    at n.$apply (ionic.bundle.min.js:166)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (ionic.bundle.min.js:446)
    at HTMLButtonElement.Gf.c (ionic.bundle.min.js:66)
    at n (ionic.bundle.min.js:22)(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:139(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:111(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:151n.$eval @ ionic.bundle.min.js:165n.$digest @ ionic.bundle.min.js:163n.$apply @ ionic.bundle.min.js:166(anonymous function) @ ionic.bundle.min.js:446Gf.c @ ionic.bundle.min.js:66n @ ionic.bundle.min.js:22t @ ionic.bundle.min.js:22l @ ionic.bundle.min.js:22

loginController.js:13 undefined
```

I still don't get the **HTTP status code 200**. What is wrong with the code?

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your API end point supports `POST` requests? It seems like you are sending a post request and your API end point expects something else.

You may try something like

`curl --data "username=value1&password=value2" https://www.****.***/****/****`

to test from the console.

Comment: yes, the API supports `POST` requests. I tryed the `curl` command and I got the Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`. Is my Code (service and controller) OK?

Answer (score 0):

This is known as CORS isssue.
You can get more idea from following link.
[Handling CORS issues with ionic](http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/)

This is because you have to setup a proxy server for that.
Because you are running your application on one domain and ajax is calling on another domain.

This can be solved by simply follow few steps

1. Open you ionic.project file
2. Add following code as per your requirement

   {
     "name": "project_name",
     "app_id": "",
     "proxies": [
       {
         "path": "/yoursite/services/",
         "proxyUrl": "http://www.yoursite.com/yoursite/services/"
       }
     ]
   }

This means it replaced http://locahost:8100/yoursite/services with http://www.yoursite.com/yoursite/services/

hope it may be helpful to you

**Below is the working code for sending data to server**

```
$http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: $loginUrl,
         headers: {
           'Content-Type': "application/json"
         }
     }).success(function(){
          //perform some action on success
     })
```

Comment: Do you think that my code is correct? or you had a suggestion for improvement?

Comment: Take a look at edit...it might be helpful now.. it is the working code of mine... @Ramosta